# Database is locking but all statements are followed by commit?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm working on an IRC bot, forked from a modular bot called Skybot.

There are two other modules that make use of the sqlite3 database by default; they have both been removed and their tables dropped, so I know that the issue is somewhere in what I'm doing.

I only call 3 `db.execute()` statements in the whole thing and they're all immediately committed. This thing isn't getting hammered with queries either, but the lock remains.

Relevant code:

```
def db_init(db):
    db.execute("create table if not exists searches"
               "(search_string UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,link)")
    db.commit()

    return db


def get_link(db, inp):
        row = db.execute("select link from searches where"
                         " search_string=lower(?) limit 1",
                         (inp.lower(),)).fetchone()
    db.commit()
    return row


def store_link(db, stub, search):
    db.execute("insert into searches (search_string, link) VALUES (?, ?)", (search.lower(), stub))
    db.commit()
    return stub
```

If the script only has to touch `db_init()` and `get_link()` it breezes through, but if it needs to call `store_link()` while the database is unlocked it will do the insert, but doesn't seem to be committing it in a way that future calls to `get_link()` can read it until the bot restarts.

The bot's db.py:

```
import os
import sqlite3


def get_db_connection(conn, name=''):
"returns an sqlite3 connection to a persistent database"

if not name:
    name = '%s.%s.db' % (conn.nick, conn.server)

filename = os.path.join(bot.persist_dir, name)
return sqlite3.connect(filename, isolation_level=None)

bot.get_db_connection = get_db_connection
```

I did adjust the `isolation_level` myself, that was originally `timeout=10`. I am fairly stumped.

EDIT: The usages of `get_db_connection()`:

main.py (main loop):

```
def run(func, input):
args = func._args

if 'inp' not in input:
    input.inp = input.paraml

if args:
    if 'db' in args and 'db' not in input:
        input.db = get_db_connection(input.conn)
    if 'input' in args:
        input.input = input
    if 0 in args:
        out = func(input.inp, **input)
    else:
        kw = dict((key, input[key]) for key in args if key in input)
        out = func(input.inp, **kw)
else:
    out = func(input.inp)
if out is not None:
    input.reply(unicode(out))
```

...

```
def start(self):
    uses_db = 'db' in self.func._args
    db_conns = {}
    while True:
        input = self.input_queue.get()

        if input == StopIteration:
            break

        if uses_db:
            db = db_conns.get(input.conn)
            if db is None:
                db = bot.get_db_connection(input.conn)
                db_conns[input.conn] = db
            input.db = db

        try:
            run(self.func, input)
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
```

Comment: You are using the cursor to commit, try conn.commit().

Comment: You commit on the connection, and execute on the cursor. You are doing `.commit()` on the cursor.

Comment: Interesting. I was just sort of going by what the other modules were doing, which would indicate they were also problematic. I did see one of them in a traceback. In trying conn.commit() I get a `NameError: global name 'conn' is not defined`.

Comment: Your problem is that you have more than one connection. Show where and how `get_db_connection` is called.

Comment: Updated the question with the `get_db_connection()` usage.

Answer (score 0):

Send conn in your functions, along with db, as mentioned. If you wrote the code yourself, you'll know where the database actually is. Conventionally you would do something like:

```
db      = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
conn    = db.cursor()
```

Then for general usage:

```
    db.execute("...")
    conn.commit()
```

Hence, in your case:

```
def db_init(conn,db):
    db.execute("create table if not exists searches"
               "(search_string UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,link)")
    conn.commit()

    return db 


def get_link(conn,db, inp):
        row = db.execute("select link from searches where"
                         " search_string=lower(?) limit 1",
                         (inp.lower(),)).fetchone()
    conn.commit()
    return row


def store_link(conn,db, stub, search):
    db.execute("insert into searches (search_string, link) VALUES (?, ?)", (search.lower(), stub))
    conn.commit()
    return stub
```

Answer (score 0):

On the basis that you have set the isolation_level to automatic updates:

```
sqlite3.connect(filename, isolation_level=None)
```

There is no need whatsoever for the `commit` statements in your code

Edit:
Wrap your `execute` statements in `try` statements, so that you at least have a chance of finding out what is going on i.e.

```
import sqlite3
def get_db(name=""):
    if not name:
        name = "db1.db"
    return sqlite3.connect(name, isolation_level=None)
connection = get_db()
cur = connection.cursor()
try:
    cur.execute("create table if not exists searches"
               "(search_string UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,link)")
except sqlite3.Error as e:
    print 'Searches create Error '+str(e)
try:
    cur.execute("insert into searches (search_string, link) VALUES (?, ?)", ("my search", "other"))
except sqlite3.Error as e:
    print 'Searches insert Error '+str(e)
cur.execute("select link from searches where search_string=? limit 1", ["my search"])
s_data = cur.fetchone()
print 'Result:', s_data
```

Comment: Removed all `commit` calls, issue remains.

Comment: I didn't think that the commit statements were the issue, I was pointing out that they are totally superfluous. See my edit for debugging your issue.